# How can I fix my dual-boot machine that now fails to load Windows?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-xp

My start-up process:

Start computer

loads bios

loads grub- now i can essentially make two choices

load Ubuntu or load windows xp

I choose to load Ubuntu and everything is fine

I choose to load windows xp and i get a blinking underscore

This is a new thing since i have been dual booting for a month so far. And there was no update to either my linux or my windows. So far this problem is arbitrary. My grub configure file is still there and as far as i can tell correct i can post it here (this is only the windows part):

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0E9FECDB5A92D74A
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

Any pointers would be helpful. I don't want to run the grub autocorrect right now -- it deleted my Windows options in the past when I've used it.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Edit: i also found my boot.ini it seems fine but herer it is:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
```

Edit2: I manually attempted to boot to xp and recreated the problem. So the problem is mot likely not with grub but with xp not wanting to boot up.

Comment: Try using SuperGrub Disk. It allows you to boot into existing OS using it. If it doesn't work, the problem probably is with xp.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Enter to Ubuntu
Enter to terminal and write:

$ sudo update-grub2

This will make that ubuntu to detect the O.S. in your computer.

I hope that this could fix your problem.

Comment: grub detects the os it just doesnt boot it. I feel that there is a problem from xp's side.